# ComboBoxCell Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a DataGridView, which has a ComboBoxColumn. This column is binded to a DataTable:

```
   With dtYesOrNo
        .Rows.Clear()
        .Columns.Clear()

        .Columns.Add("Description")
        .Columns.Add("Code")

        Dim statusRow = dtYesOrNo.NewRow
        statusRow("Description") = ""
        statusRow("Code") = 101
        dtYesOrNo.Rows.Add(statusRow)

        statusRow = dtYesOrNo.NewRow
        statusRow("Description") = "Yes"
        statusRow("Code") = 102
        dtYesOrNo.Rows.Add(statusRow)

        statusRow = dtYesOrNo.NewRow
        statusRow("Description") = "No"
        statusRow("Code") = 103
        dtYesOrNo.Rows.Add(statusRow)
    End With
```

Then I set DisplayMember to "Description", and ValueMember to "Code".

```
Dim colUECStatus As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    With colUECStatus
        .DataSource = dtYesOrNo
        .DataPropertyName = "StatusChk"
        .Name = "StatusChk"
        .DisplayMember = "Description"
        .ValueMember = "Code"

        'Combobox Formatting
        .HeaderText = "Status"
        .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
        .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192)
        UECgrid.Columns.Insert(0, colUECStatus)
    End With
```

But my problem is that when I actually load the form, it is giving me an exception for not having a valid value in my combox. For example, if the selection is "", the combo box would display 101, instead of "". 
And here's the code where I load my grid (Note: please ignore the grid names -- UECgrid and dgvUEC1 are the same grid):

```
        Dim row = 0
    For Each checklist In USEFileChecklistUSChecklist.GetGeneralChecklist
        objEFile.dgvUEC1.Rows(row).Cells("StatusChk").Value = checklist.statusCode

        row += 1
    Next
```

Comment: Value of the column `StatusChk` must be found from the `ComboBox` datasource in the column which defined as `ValueMember`. So in your case value of `StatusChk` must `101`, `102` or `103`

Comment: Yes. In my load method (3rd block of code), I'm actually loading in integers (101, 102, or 103) into objEFile.dgvUEC1.Rows(row).Cells("StatusChk").Value. But when the form is displayed, it first gives me an error: 

The following exception occured in the DataGridView
System.FormatException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
To replace this default dilaog please handle the data error event

Then, it would go to the next line, and I noticed that the combo box in the previous line is filled with 101, 102, 103, instead of "", "Yes", "No"

Comment: As I understand you are adding `StatusChk` values after row was added to the `DataGridView`. Exception will be thrown because when row was added to the `DataGridView` value of `StatusChk` is empty

Comment: I found a way to fix it. Thank you!